# How to open a cdf file in R correctly?

Tags: netcdf

I can't get the netcdf file to open in R, it says the path is invalid. However, the same path runs perfectly in Matlab so the path is not the issue. R can't read / (forward slashes) only \ (backwards slashes), but my file directory automatically uses forward slashes. Not suer what to do the two sections of code are the different errors I get.

```
ncpath <- "C:\Users\Madison-Riley\Desktop\Thesis\Environmental_Data\Temperature\"
ncname <- "Temp_Q1(2020)"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
dname <- "temp"  # note: tmp means temperature (not temporary)
```

Show in New Window
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)`

```
ncpath <- "C:/Users/Madison-Riley/Desktop/Thesis/Environmental_Data/Temperature/"
ncname <- "Temp_Q1(2020)"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
dname <- "temp"  # note: tmp means temperature (not temporary)
```

Error in nc_open(ncfname) :
Error in nc_open trying to open file C:/Users/Madison-Riley/Desktop/Thesis/Environmental_Data/Temperature/Temp_Q1(2020).nc (return_on_error= FALSE )

I tried both forward and backward slashes neither works